# Index field using: new TextField(String fieldName, Reader reader)

Tags: lucene

I've been trying to index a field using the readerValue() that Lucene provides in the Fields. The thing is that the terms are not being indexed. This is the interesting part of the code:

```java
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
indexWriter.deleteAll();
String str = "Some random text to be indexed";
Reader reader = new StringReader(str);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("content", reader));          
indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

Now, if I index that text as a String with the other TextField constructor it works fine, but like this it does not index the terms, instead returns null when I try to get the value of the field after a search:

```java
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("content",  new SimpleAnalyzer());  
Query query = queryParser.parse(text);
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query,10);
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {           
     Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
     Reader r = document.getField("content").readerValue();
```

I really can't see the problem, maybe it is some dumb thing that I missed, or maybe I'm using it wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `TextField` is unstored.  The behavior you are seeing is expected for an un-stored field.  You should be able to search on it, but not retrieve it from the index.  The constructor that takes a string argument for the field contents allows you to set whether to store the field or not, thus the different behavior.

The reason the store option is not available on that constructor, is that Lucene explicitly disallows a stored field to be set with a `Reader` or `TokenStream` value.  If you want to store the field, you will simply need get the string value from the `Reader` yourself.